# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n a_n$ where $a_{n+1} = \frac{\sqrt{a_{n}^2 + 1} - 1}{a_n}$ and $a_1 = 1$

Tags: calculus, limits

**Problem**

Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n a_n$ where $a_1 = 1$ and $$a_{n+1} = \frac{\sqrt{a_{n}^2 + 1} - 1}{a_n}$$

---

I saw a similar problems and they solved with trigonometric functions for $a_n$, but I can't apply that to this problem.

I just checked boundedness and monotone, $0<a_{n+1}<1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trigonometric substitution $a_n=\tan \alpha_n$, works just fine. We have $\alpha_1=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and:

$$\tan \alpha_{n+1}=\frac{\sqrt{\tan^2 \alpha_n+1}-1}{\tan \alpha_n}=\tan \frac{\alpha_n}{2}$$

and thus $a_{n+1}=\tan \alpha_{n+1}=\tan \dfrac{\alpha_n}{2}=\tan \dfrac{\alpha_{n-1}}{4}=\ldots=\tan \dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+2}}$. Therefore:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} 2^n\tan\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(2^{n}\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\cdot \frac{\tan\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$