# How can I get $\lim2^na_n$? : $a_{n+1}=\frac{\sqrt{a_n^2+1}-1}{a_n}$

Tags: limits

How can I get $\lim2^na_n$, for $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{\sqrt{a_n^2+1}-1}{a_n}$?

I've tried using $b_n=a_n^{-1}$ and I got $b_{n+1}=\sqrt{b_n^2+1}+b_n$, but I cannot get a better idea or further step.

Let $\frac {b_n}{2^n}=c_n$ and $\lim c_n=C$, then I get $C=\frac C2+\frac C2$, a trivial equation.

Any help is welcomed...

Comment: is $ n\to \infty$?

Comment: Of course, @RamanujanXV I learned that I can skip $n\to\infty$ because most of them are $n\to\infty$ when I find the limit of the sequence, but is it not true that I learned?

Comment: Well,frankly speakin I haven't heard of such a thing but it may exist.We have to wait till someone more knowledgeable would tell us about this.

Comment: @RamanujanXV I think the limit does exist ($\approx 1.5707963267948981$). However, from the numerical point of view, it is preferable to consider the equivalent formulation
$$
a_{n+1} = \dfrac{a_n}{\sqrt{a_n^2+1}+1}.
$$

Comment: @PierreCarre it looks like $\frac{\pi}{2}$ ;)

Comment: [Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n a_n$ where $a_{n+1} = \frac{\sqrt{a_{n}^2 + 1} - 1}{a_n}$ and $a_1 = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557438/find-lim-n-to-infty-2n-a-n-where-a-n1-frac-sqrta-n2-1-1) is the same question, which uses a tangent substitution to solve the problem. The answer is indeed $\frac \pi 2$. Found with [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the equivalent recursion formula
$$
a_{n+1} = \dfrac{a_n}{1+\sqrt{a_n^2+1}},
$$

it is easy to see that $a_n \to 0$, $a_n$ is decreasing, and also that $a_{n+1} < \frac 12 a_n$. Additionally, since
$$
2^{n+1}a_{n+1} - 2^n a_n=2^{n}(2a_{n+1}-a_n) < 0,
$$

we can establish that $2^n a_n$ is decreasing and, therefore  $0 < 2^n a_n < 2$. A bounded and decreasing sequence is convergent. The limit seems to be $\frac{\pi}{2}$ but I did not prove this.